# How to limit properties of a JSON object given array of property names using JQ?

Tags: arrays, json, object, filter, jq

Assuming I have the following JSON object *(which is just an example):*

```
{ 
  "foo": 1, 
  "bar": 2, 
  "baz": 3 
}
```

And the following JSON array *(another example):*

```
["foo", "baz"]
```

How could I use [**jq**](https://stedolan.github.io/jq) to output the following object?

```
{ 
  "foo": 1, 
  "baz": 3 
}
```

I hate asking this question because I feel certain it has been answered before, but google has failed me and my jq-fu is just not where it needs to be to figure this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided that `.` is the object and `$arr` is the array, the following does the trick

```
delpaths(keys - $arr | map([.]))
```

Answer (score 2):

Using a `reduce` to iteratively build up the result object would be one way:

```sh
echo '["foo", "baz"]' | jq --argjson index '{"foo":1,"bar":2,"baz":3}' '
  reduce .[] as $x ({}; .[$x] = $index[$x])
'
```

Using `JOIN`, creating key-value pairs, and employing `from_entries` for assembly would be another way:

```sh
echo '["baz", "foo"]' | jq --argjson index '{"foo":1,"bar":2,"baz":3}' '
  JOIN($index; .) | map({key:.[0], value:.[1]}) | from_entries
'
```

Output:

```json
{
  "foo": 1,
  "baz": 3
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer.  oguz's answer is much cleaner for my current use-case, but I will have to study yours too as I am sure I can learn something useful from it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a reduce-free solution that assumes $keys is the array of keys of interest and that is possibly more efficient than the one involving array subtraction:

```
. as $in | INDEX( $keys[]; $in[.] )
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the desired result, one could write:

```
 jq '{foo, baz}'
```

This can (with some considerable trepidation) be made into a solution for the given problem by text wrangling, e.g. along the lines of:

```
jq "$(echo '["foo", "baz"]' | jq -Rr '"{" + .[1:-1] + "}" ')"
```

or

```
jq "$(echo '["foo", "baz"]' | sed -e 's/\[/{/' -e 's/\]/}/')"
```